# How can I remote desktop to windows host in linux?

Tags: remote-desktop

I use   wine + teamviewer on fedora   to remote to windows host. The teamviewer is work fine but the performance of wine is so bad. It make my CPU high. Is there any linux tool for remote desktop to windows and any windows tool for remote to linux desktop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mfriedman suggested you want [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/), it is much easier to use it with the [tsclient](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/packages/name/tsclient), [gnome-rdp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnome-rdp/), or [krdc](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdenetwork/krdc/index.html) frontends.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/) to establish an RDP session from Linux to a Windows system.

To do the opposite (i.e., connect to a Linux desktop from Windows) there are several options. For example, you could run a VNC server on your Linux box and connect from Windows by using a VNC client.

Comment: -g flag for resolution.

rdesktop server -g 1280x1024

Answer (score 2):

GNOME (on Ubuntu, I'm pretty sure it is part of GNOME proper) includes [tsclient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsclient), which is a fancy front end to rdesktop (with saved profiles, checkboxes/dropdowns for everything, etc).